# Apple iOS Shortcuts App - how to include spoken variable in the initial command?

Tags: ios, shortcut, siri, shortcuts-app

Despite having a BSc in Software Engineering I am struggling with iOS shortcuts...

What I would like to do is include the text for a shortcut (I am trying to create a new shortcut to add a task to Microsoft ToDo App) in the initial command.

So, instead of saying "Hey Siri, let's add a work Task" and then Siri asking what it is, I would like to say "Hey Siri, add a work Task to pay the monthly telecom invoice."

Is this possible? I know it is with native commands such as the iOS...

Comment: I understand what you're asking and it is possible but the method of doing it is too tiresome (Even though you have a BSc) and personally, I would recommend you to just say the name of the task another time like you already do. If you wanna have a look at parametrized shortcuts then here you go. Apple's Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app and a rather well explain doc by Andy Ibanez: https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/parametrized-shortcuts/